# Custom Element issue: ref element is null in viewmodel

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a custom element in Aurelia that uses a jQuery plugin under the hood (KendoUI). This custom element is being used within a view that uses the `if.bind` attribute.

The custom element uses an inline template, like so:

```
@inlineView('<template><input type="text" ref="proxy" class.bind="class"></template>')
```

Due to the nature of the jQuery plugin, I have to pass an element to initialize. I use the ref that I've defined in my template, like so:

```
$(this.proxy).doJQueryStuff(...)
```

After the element is detached, and then reattached, the ref element (`this.proxy` in my viewmodel) is null.

I initially thought that the problem was that since jQuery mutates the DOM, it was also mutating the view template. I thought that after the element is detached (and destroyed with a jQuery call to remove all KendoUI metadata), the input ref was no longer available resulting in an error upon reattachment because Aurelia was caching the view. However, this is not the case. It's been confirmed that Aurelia doesn't cache views unless you explicitly tell it to do so, and in [this simplified plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/yqmPVJ/preview), the behavior is as expected.

Why would the reference to my ref element, in my viewmodel, be null after attaching and detaching the element?

Of note, the custom element is part of a page view, inside this construct:

```
<div id="application" class="au-animate" if.bind="isLoggedIn">
    <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>
    <div class="page-host">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if anyone has run into any problems with a `router-view` inside of an `if` binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed this evening by [this pull request](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/pull/150).  Run `jspm update` and confirm you have `github:aurelia/templating-resources@0.17.3` installed.

The issue was the `if` template controller was not rebinding the view when re-attaching it to the DOM after it had been hidden.

Comment: No dice. Just updated and it looks as though I'm still seeing the issue. I'll try to update my plunk.

Comment: I don't think that Plunker supports routing examples in Aurelia. I've placed my example here: http://jedd-ahyoung.github.io/if-bind-test. There's a custom element (autocomplete in this case) that loses its binding when you toggle the router-view.

Comment: Rather, it can't be rebound because the ref element becomes null after toggling the if binding.

Comment: it looks like you're still on 0.17.2 of templating-resources:
http://jedd-ahyoung.com/if-bind-test/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.17.2/if.js

Comment: Cripes. I updated this morning in my project and still saw the same issue, but I put the test case together using the skeleton navigation. I'll update the deps after lunch and push out to github. I believe the problem is still present.

Comment: Updated the dependencies - still seeing the same problem with `templating-resources@0.17.3`, `templating@0.17.4`, and `binding@0.11.3`. Changes should be live on github (and in the master branch).

Comment: definitely seems like an issue.  thanks for the repro- will get this fixed tonight.